# Java/SeleniumWebDriver: Focus Don't skip to Else If block when the warning message matches on webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm working on webpage which displays warning message when Invalid username or password is entered. When the invalid details are entered, the message displayed will be changed and says user is blocked. I was trying to capture these different messages in a try/catch block. However, my code don't shift focus to else if block based on the warning message that I'm verifying.

Code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("submitted")).click();

    try {           
             if (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']"), "No Password Found for"))){

            String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
            System.out.println(text);

            if(text.contentEquals("No Password Found for")){
        driver.navigate().refresh();

                Assert.fail("Unable to login to application");
            }
            }

             else if(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']"), "Your Online/Mobile Banking User ID has been blocked. Please go to “Forgot Password” option to unblock it."))){

String retext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

            System.out.println(retext);

            if(retext.contentEquals("Your Online/Mobile Banking User ID has been blocked. Please go to “Forgot Password” option to unblock it.")) {
                driver.navigate().refresh();

                Assert.fail("Unable to login to application");
            }


        }       

             else if (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']"), "Time Out"))){
            String timeouttext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

            if(timeouttext.contentEquals("You have specified an invalid User Name or Password. Please check and try again")){
                driver.navigate().refresh();

                                    Assert.fail("Unable to login to application");      }


        }
```

Comment: @DebanjanB I have raised new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your try includes all conditions, i assume that when it fails to find first element and throws exception, it skips all the rest body of try.

Do something like this:

```
try {
if (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']"), "No Password Found for")))
             {
                String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
                System.out.println(text);
                if(text.contentEquals("No Password Found for"))
                {
                    driver.navigate().refresh();
                    Assert.fail("Unable to login to application");
                }
            }
}
catch(Exception){}
try{
if(new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']"), "Your Online/Mobile Banking User ID has been blocked. Please go to “Forgot Password” option to unblock it.")))
             {
                String retext = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='small-9 small-pull-1 column content']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");
                System.out.println(retext);
                if(retext.contentEquals("Your Online/Mobile Banking User ID has been blocked. Please go to “Forgot Password” option to unblock it.")) 
                {
                    driver.navigate().refresh();
                    Assert.fail("Unable to login to application");
                }
            }
catch(Exception){}
```

And so on.

Though, it will be better for performance to get text from this element, and evaluate it, instead of multiple attempts to find element.